# jquery find function with || ">*"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I read a sample code I don't understand.

Do you know what `|| ">*"` means in find function ?

```
$.fn.ignore = function (sel) {
    return this.clone().find(sel || ">*").remove().end();
};
```

What is the difference with find(sel) ?

Comment: If `sel` is `undefined` it'll use `">*"` instead.

Comment: The difference is that if no `sel` is passed in it'll use `">*"`.

Comment: It will delete all children of current elemen, if there is no selector ( sel ).

Comment: Thanks, I have my answer :-)